# Camel: find qualified name of the web service interface that invoked the route

Tags: java, rest, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I have a CXF web service that is invoked by a Camel route. Then the actual execution is done by some `SomethingDoerBean` which is invoked as one of the endpoints of the Camel route.

Here is the interface of the web service. It works with both `SOAP` and `REST` requests.

```
package my.company.service;

@WebService(name = "SomethingDoerService", targetNamespace = "my.company/SomethingDoerService")
public interface SomethingDoerService {

    @GET
    @Path("/somepath/{userId}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "myResponse")
    public MyResponse doSomething(
        @HeaderParam("myHeader") @WebParam(name = "MyHeader", header = true, targetNamespace = "my.company") MyHeader myHeader,
        @PathParam("userId")   @WebParam(name = "userId") String userId);
}
```

Here is the route configuration:

```
<!-- soap requests -->
<route id="SoapSomethingDoerService">
    <from uri="cxf:bean:somethingDoerService" />
    <to uri="direct:somethingDoerOperation" />
</route>

<!-- rest requests -->
<route id="RestSomethingDoerService">
    <from uri="cxfrs:/rest/somethingDoerOperation?resourceClasses=my.company.service.somethingDoerOperation&amp;bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer&amp;providers=#restJacksonProviderList" />
    <to uri="direct:somethingDoerOperation" />
</route>

<route id="SomethingDoerOperationRoute">
    <from uri="direct:somethingDoerOperation" />
    ...............
    <to uri="bean:somethingDoerBean?method=doSomethingReal" />
    ...............
</route>
```

Within `SomethingDoerBean`, I would like to know programmatically, what the qualified name is of the web service interface that invoked the route (in this case it is `my.company.service.SomethingDoerService`). How could I achieve this? I don't see anything on the Camel `exchange` interface that allows me to get it....

Comment: You could try to inspect `CamelCxfMessage` header contents.

Comment: Thanks. `exchange.getIn().getHeader("serviceClassName", String.class)`